# Rails mailer.text emaillink not reidrecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm sending out confirmation emails to users once they sign up. The html email redirects back to my app when they click the confirm your account link but the .text email does redirect back. The log is saying that the information is being processed, but I want them to be redirected so they can input their info.

```
.text.erb

Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.email %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.email %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

Comment: What's being rendered in the email?

Comment: The email appears as expected, with text and link that says confirm my account. When you click the link, the logs show that the account is confirmed but you just stay on the email page. There is no redirect back to the site once the link is clicked

Comment: You mean you never leave your mail client?  You're expecting the user to open their mail client, open the message, click on the link, and then be redirected to the site - but instead they just stay in the mail client?  What exactly is the URL that's embedded in the email?

Comment: Yes exactly. As for the URL, I'm not positive because I'm using Devise, but I do know that I have the same link in my .html email and it redirects as expected.  Also I have this in my development.rb file:  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }